# On proving that the sum $\sqrt{1001^2 + 1}+\sqrt{1002^2 + 1} \ + ... + \sqrt{2000^2 + 1}$ is irrational using trigonometry.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometric-series

> Prove that the sum $$ \sqrt{1001^2 + 1}+\sqrt{1002^2 + 1} \ + ... + \sqrt{2000^2 + 1}$$
> is irrational.

Well the problem though have good algaebric solution I was wondering whether it's possible to solve it using this approach or not ?

Let $(1000+k) = \tan(\theta)$ . Then,

$\sqrt{(1000+k)^2+1} = \sec(\theta)$

Similarly the required sum would be summation of n sec thetas for n distinct thetas .

But i can't proceed this way so help if possible.

Comment: I don't think this approach works. Even if you succeed to find a nice formula for the sum, for example $S = \tan(\alpha))$. From the value of $\alpha$, how do you prove $ \tan(\alpha)) \notin \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @NN2 If x is a non-zero real algebraic number, sin(x), cos(x) and tan(x)
 are all transcendental. This is a consequence of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem. This means that the above sum cannot be solved using trignometry because the sum is irrational and not transcadental.